# IndentationError: unexpected indent (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

i'm trying to load my scrapy but, as you can see, there's a error:

```
File "rotina\spiders\rotina1.py", line 4, in <module>
from rotina.items import ImobiliariasItem
File "rotina\items.py", line 6
tipo = Field()
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

My items.py is:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

    categoria = Field()
    tipo = Field()
    qtd_quartos = Field()
    qtd_banheiros = Field()
    qtd_garagem = Field()
    descricao = Field()
    photo = Field()
```

What can i do?

Comment: You're missing the last line which says the specific error.

Comment: Try deleting that line and write it again.

Comment: Also, turn on the option to display invisible characters in your text editor, and make that a habit when you're coding in python.

Comment: If you need more help or if you have any other questions - please add a comment to the answer.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, please add more details.

Answer (score 2):

A general item declaration is missing. The interpreter does not know to
which item it should assign the fields:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):

    categoria = Field()
    tipo = Field()
    qtd_quartos = Field()
    qtd_banheiros = Field()
    qtd_garagem = Field()
    descricao = Field()
    photo = Field()
```

Check out this example in the documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#declaring-items

In order to get the indentation straight - you can use tools like **tabnanny**: http://pymotw.com/2/tabnanny/